# Process Explorer does not show the real CPU load

Tags: windows, cpu, performance, process-explorer

I notice that my computer becomes significantly slower while [µTorrent](https://www.utorrent.com) is running. For example starting new programs takes anormally long and programs react more slowly. When I shut down µTorrent all works normal again.

I have a 3.5 Ghz AMD A8-5600K CPU with 4 cores. My computer is normally very fast. But µTorrent slows it down although it is only making some TCP connections to other peers. It does not even write to the disk because it is currently only seeding.

[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) from SysInternals shows me a wrong CPU load. The following screenshot is ordered by column "CPU" and shows the process with the highest load at the top.

[image: µTorrent CPU Load]

If µTorrent would really only use 1.16% of the 4 CPU cores, why is my computer so slow then?

I had the same problem when my last harddisk was already dying and had read problems in some sectors. My computer was extremely slow and Process Explorer showed the same wrong CPU load.

I suppose that internally a driver is using much of the CPU and this is not shown in Process Explorer. If the real CPU load is this:

```
100% CPU = Drivers + "System Idle Process" + all other processes
```

Process Explorer omits the CPU used by the drivers and calculates with a wrong value for what is 100%.

**My question:**

What software can I use which shows me the real load of the CPU including the drivers?

Comment: So you're using a HDD, yes? That's your problem. I/O load, not CPU load. You can easily check that, too, for example using Task Manager.

Comment: µTorrent and similar software has never been known as software that doesn't have high I/O demands. The BitTorrent in general protocol is inefficient.

Comment: uTorrent also has earned a bad reputation for loading questionable or even malicious software. While no Torrent application is particularly efficient, there are programs with better reputations, less likely to drop badware on computers it is installed on. Currently, I use qTorrent, which has a good reputation in this regard.

Comment: I would like to, once again, recommend you check your I/O load. [Task Manager’s Performance tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI2Wc.png) is the place to go. If “Active time” reaches or nears 100%, your storage is so busy, it cannot service (other) requests anymore, which can bring your entire system to a halt. So much in fact that your mouse cursor could freeze.

Answer (score 1):

You ask, "If µTorrent would really only use 1.16% of the 4 CPU cores, why is my computer so slow then?" The answer could be a number of reasons. most likely, *CPU usage is being reported accurately,* but the speed is limited by an operation **other** than CPU, for example disk input/output (I/O).

[image: I/O Processes]

In the *Task Manger* image above, note that I/O Reads and Writes are using a lot of resources for a few processes. HDD access is thousands of times slower than that of CPU or RAM, and even SSD speeds are far, far slower than that of the CPU.

Think of it as a race car with a huge engine, but running on wheels from a skateboard. A more powerful engine is *not* the answer to more speed.

As you already stated, "I had the same problem when my last harddisk was already dying." Even with a healthy drive, that is the bottleneck, **not the CPU**, if there is a lot of I/O, as in saving or uploading files in a Torrent. Try another Torrent client, such as [qBittorent](https://www.qbittorrent.org/), to see if it is more efficient, or use a SSD to speed things.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is does not answer my question. What I want is a software that shows me that µTorrent is actually the software which is making my computer slow. If not by CPU load it should show that it is the IO Load or interrupts or whatever which makes my computer slow. But I want to see which process is causing this slowness.

Comment: µTorrent is just one example of a software which may make my computer slow. So your suggestion of using another torrent software is not what I'am looking for. I search for a diagnosis software to show me why my computer is slow and who is causing this. Does this not exist???

Comment: @Elmue DrMoishe showed you a utility that does that, but also, as the Help section states, we do not entertain requests for software products on this site, for a variety of reasons. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Until now I did not find a software which shows me exactly that µTorrent is the culprit of the slowness, but I found out that I can enable another column in Process Explorer which in deed shows me µTorrent at the top of all all other processes: The column "CPU cycles":

[image: Process Explorer shows why computer is slow]

This screenshot gives me the impression that it is not I/O access which makes my computer slow, because the I/O Reads and writes are not significantly higher than in other processes.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but you are wrong. Compared to the idle process (and the sum of all others), this is highly insignificant. Your problem is I/O load (of your HDD). Not all I/O is equal.